# Замена нескольких символов в строке на один символ

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Нужна Ваша помощь!

Задача такова:

Между словами может быть один или несколько пробелов, требуется заменить одиночный пробел или группу пробелов на символ "*". Я смог заменить одиночный символ, а как сделать замену нескольких символов, голову сломал. Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
public class PeplaceSpace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String thisString = "мама мыла раму";
        String replaceSpace = thisString.replace(" ", "*");

        System.out.println(replaceSpace);

    }
}
```

Comment: javascript здесь причём?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class PeplaceSpace {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String thisString = "мама    мыла       раму";
    String replaceSpace = thisString.replaceAll("\\s+", "*");

    System.out.println(replaceSpace);

    }
}
```

Comment: \\s   –  пробельный символ, regexp

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите на метод replaceAll в классе String